# Solving a system of linear equations in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Given the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 &\bigm| & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & -1 &\bigm| & 0 \\
    0 & -4 & 4 &\bigm| & 0 
\end{bmatrix}

Attempt: Using some matrix operations (changing equation 3 by the sum of (4 times equation 2) and (equation 3)), I transformed the given matrix to
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 &\bigm| & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & -1 &\bigm| & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 &\bigm| & 0 
\end{bmatrix}

Therefore,
$x= -z$ and $y=z$, so the solution is $(-z, z, z).$

Are my solution and answer valid?

Comment: Yes, that's the solution.

Comment: Yes, note that equations 2 and 3 are basically the same and that's why you're getting a row full of zeroes at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually if you transform a linear equation $Ax=0$ to $Rx=0$ where
\begin{equation}
R =\left[\begin{array}{ll}
I & F \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
and denote $x$ as
\begin{equation}
x = \left[\begin{array}{l}
x_i \\
x_j 
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
here $I$ is an identity matrix, $F$ is a block matrix. From above equations, we obtain
\begin{align}
I x_i + F x_j = 0 \\
x_i = -F x_j 
\end{align}
In this example,
\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{l}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{array}\right]=-\left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
-1
\end{array}\right] x_3=\left[\begin{array}{c}
-1 \\
1
\end{array}\right] x_3
\end{equation}
Hence, your solution is valid.

Remark: the above statement is not religious since   we omit the dimensions of $I$ and $F$.